# ParallelQuery.ForAll and IEnumerable.ForEach

Tags: linq, naming-conventions

Why these two methods, while having the same semantics have different names (For`All` and For`Each`)?

Comment: Maybe to make it easier to distinguish between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ForEach` method is **not** a method that is defined by `IEnumerable`, it is an instance method of `List<T>`!

So this is nearly the explanation. `ForEach` is the counterpart for the known `foreach` loop and there is no difference between:

```
foreach (var item in list) { ... }
```

and

```
list.ForEach(...);
```

On the other hand there is `ForAll` from `ParallelEnumerable` where I think they named it like this, because they did not want you to think that it is just a `foreach` loop, which it is not, because the actions are executed parallel.

Comment: Not sure if I get the last part of your answer. Do you mean, that `ForEach` names implies that the items a will be processed **sequentially**, while a `ForAll` does not make such guarantee?

Comment: Yeah depending on the data within the objects that are worked with, the item at index 5 could be used before the item on index 4.

Comment: Not only does ForAll not make a guarantee regarding the order of execution/completion, the whole point of it is to execute in parallel.  Order could be fairly arbitrary and you should assume as much when using it.